# Style settings with no effect on D3 network diagram

Tags: d3.js

I am teaching myself D3 by working through examples.  Right now, I'm working through Michael Bostock's forced network example of a molecule, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3037015.

- In the style settings, the line separator and the circle are both assigned stroke-widths.  However, I do not see any change in the diagram when I change or remove these stroke-width settings.
- Also in the style settings, pointer-events is set to none for the text.  However, I do not see any change in the diagram when I change this setting from none to all.

Why do changes to these settings have no effect?  Why are these settings made in the example if they have no effect?

I am using local copies of D3 (d3.v3.js) and the data (graph.json) and viewing the diagrams on Firefox 20.0.1 for Windows.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried with another browser? This is almost certainly a browser thing.

Comment: I tried changing the css stroke-width in Firebug and both the line separator and circles are changed accordingly.